# buttons on expense manager not working - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two buttons in my expense manager: 'Add Income' and 'Add Expense' which allow the user to add their income and expenses but they don't work and I'm not sure why. I have onclick listeners for both of the 'add expense' and 'add income buttons. What do I need to change in my JS code to solve this?

```
const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4')

// Read existing expenses from localStorage
const getSavedExpenses = () => {
    const expensesJSON = localStorage.getItem('expenses')

    try {
    return expensesJSON ? JSON.parse(expensesJSON) : []
} catch (e) {
    return []
}
}
const expenses = getSavedExpenses()

// Save expenses to localStorage
const saveExpenses = (expenses) => {
localStorage.setItem('expenses', JSON.stringify(expenses))
}

const displayExpenses = (title, expensesJSON) => {

    let html = `<div class="text-expense">`

    for (let i = 0; i < expensesJSON.length; i++) {
        html += `<textarea type="text" id="description" name="description"></textarea>`
}
    html += `</div>`

    title.innerHTML = html;
}


// Create account
const account = {
    name: 'aaa',
    expenses: [],
    income: [],

    addExpense: function (description, amount) {
      this.expenses.push({
          description: description,
          amount: amount
      })
    },
    addIncome: function  (description, amount) {
        this.income.push({
            description: description, 
            amount: amount
        })
    },
    getAccountSummary: function () {
        let totalExpenses = 0
        let totalIncome = 0
        let accountBalance = 0

       this.expenses.forEach(function (expense) {
           totalExpenses = totalExpenses + expense.amount
       })

        this.income.forEach(function (income) {
            totalIncome = totalIncome + income.amount
        })

        accountBalance = totalIncome - totalExpenses   

}
}

account.addExpense('Rent', 850)
account.addExpense('Food Shopping', 60)
console.log(account.getAccountSummary())


// Listen for new expense to be created
$('#add-expense').on('click', function() {
location.href = '/expense.html'
})

// Listen for expense to be submitted
$('#submit-expense').on('click', function() {
    saveExpenses(expenses)
location.href = '/index.html'
})

$('#income').on('click', function() {
    location.href = '/income.html'
})

$('#submit-income').on('click', function() {
    location.href = '/index.html'
})

$('#add-expense').on('click', function () {
    const id = uuidv4()
    expenses.push({
        id: id,
        title: '',
        body: ''
    })
    saveExpenses(expenses)
    location.href = `/expense.html#${id}`
    displayExpenses(targetElem, getSavedExpenses())
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `onclick` event handlers are wrapped inside a `onload` handler (or jQuery's `$(document).ready`), so that you are sure your buttons are loaded before `$(some_selector)` is called, something like:

```
onload = function() {
    // Listen for new expense to be created
    $('#add-expense').on('click', function() {
    location.href = '/expense.html'
    })

    // Listen for expense to be submitted
    $('#submit-expense').on('click', function() {
        saveExpenses(expenses)
    location.href = '/index.html'
    })

    $('#income').on('click', function() {
        location.href = '/income.html'
    })

    $('#submit-income').on('click', function() {
        location.href = '/index.html'
    })

    $('#add-expense').on('click', function () {
        const id = uuidv4()
        expenses.push({
            id: id,
            title: '',
            body: ''
        })
        saveExpenses(expenses)
        location.href = `/expense.html#${id}`
        displayExpenses(targetElem, getSavedExpenses())
    })
}
```